# Can `>>` operator be overloaded to able to `std::cin >> function(with_param)` in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering if it is possible if I can overload the `>>` operator?

For example in code. If I have this function that capitalize the first letter of `std::string`

```
auto capitalize_first_letter(std::string &text) -> void { 
  text[0] = toupper(text[0]); 
}
```

How can I do something like this

```
std::string word{};
std::cin >> capitalize_first_letter(word);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Overloading is possible for example to support directly outputting your own classes. Not clear exactly what you want in this case though, you can't overload on `void`. Isn't it easier to have the function return a `string`? (or `string &`)

Comment: "was wondering if it is possible if I can overload the >> operator?" - Yes. That operator can be overloaded.

Comment: There are many functions that does that. Take for example [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).

Comment: As for how to "overload" (which isn't actually what's happening) I recommend you look at [this list of overloaded `>>` operators for `std::istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). Notice the one labeled 8 to 10.

Comment: As a hint: It's easiest to do this using classes, where the constructor takes the argument you want to pass, and the class implements a suitable `operator()` function (the function call operator).

Comment: @BoBTFish Thank you for the suggestion, I should change my void function to a std::string function, I never thought of overloading on void.

Comment: It should be possible to implement an overload of this kind in some way. The end result; the code will be mostly unreadable by other C++ developers, so if it was necessary to seek their help, they won't be able to help much, with a program written in some weird code that vaguely resembles C++ code.

Comment: `std::cin >> (capitalize_first_letter(word), word);`

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to overload `>>` for functions. Many io-manipulators are functions and `>>` has overloads for them. Though `capitalize_first_letter(word)` calls the function and results in `void`. I would rather use a custom type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct capitalize_first_letter {
    std::string& value;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, capitalize_first_letter&& c){
    in >> c.value;
    if (c.value.size()) c.value[0] = toupper(c.value[0]); 
    return in;
}

int main() {
    std::string word{};
    std::cin >> capitalize_first_letter{word};
    std::cout << word;
}
```

Usually you wouldnt overload `>>` for a `T&&` but as `capitalize_first_letter` is just a wrapper, only meant to be used as temporary it is fine here.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems very clear to me

Comment: Naah! While this is a perfectly fine answer to your immediate question, the effect that is achieved is by no means clear. In my book these sorts of twisted data flow and side effects lead to insanity.

Comment: @j6t Okay Sir. Since it leads to a really bad side effects I'm no actually applying this in real world development, I was just wondering.